# Is zoom.us spying on me?

Tags: mac, spyware

I installed the zoom.us app on my Mac 3 day ago.
I have not used it for 2 days. It isn't active. I don't see it in the top app(top | grep zoom)
But there are a lot of requests in my personal DNS server log.
How to kill zoom daemon process?

[image]

Comment: While this particular application is not malware, since it is a legitimate application, it's unlikely the company is actually spying on you.  However, there have been numerous vulnerabilities that have been discovered in recent days, so only you can decide if those vulnerabilities are sever enough to warrant not using the application.  You have not really provided us information to determine an actual answer to your question, your screenshot contains the domains, I would expect from use of said application.

Comment: I quit the zoom app after a short talk 2 days ago.
Why it is sending thousands of requests every day?

Comment: The application in question has a lot of problems that have been revealed in the last couple days.  I have no idea if your situation is caused by those revelations or it's a case of the application just being badly coded.  I would encourage you do some research on those vulnerabilities.  For the time being, a simple reboot after you uninstall the software, should prevent any additional DNS queries from happening.

Comment: Evidently Zoom was data mining but mining has been removed>>>>>>https://threatpost.com/zoom-removes-data-mining-linkedin-feature/154404/